# Why is the function returned from a callback function not forming closure over the function where it is called?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble in understanding the output from the below code (In Javascript) :

```
function outerFunction(callback){
  var x =10;  
  var myCallbackRet = callback();
  myCallbackRet();     
}

outerFunction(function(){
  return function(){
    console.log(x); //output - x is not defined
  }
});
```

As far as i understand when function `myCallbackRet` is called then [[Scope]] property of `myCallbackRet` is set to the Scope chain of the `outerFunction` and so the variable `x` should be accessible inside `myCallbackRet'.

Why is the output 'undefined'? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: First of all `var myCallbackRet = callback();` should be `var myCallbackRet = callback;`

Comment: No I think its right akinuri. Callback is a function passed in that returns a function.

Comment: Actually i am calling the callback function and storing the result of the callback which itself is a function inside the variable 'myCallbackRet '.I think this is perfectly valid.

Comment: My mistake. Unindented code >.>

Answer (score 3):

Basically it has to do with where your function is defined. It was defined out of scope. Closure only works when a function is defined some where. Setting a variable to a function and calling it doesn't make everything above it available inside the function being called or there would be no reason to pass parameters to a function. Something like this would work.

```
function outerFunction(callback){
    var x =10;  
    var myCallbackRet = callback();
    myCallbackRet(x);     
}

outerFunction(function(){
    return function(y){
        console.log(y);
    }
});
```

Or this:

```
function outerFunction(callback){
    var myCallbackRet = callback();
    myCallbackRet();     
}

outerFunction(function(){
    var x =10;  
    return function(){
        console.log(x);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes the anonymous function was defined in global scope as you said.

Comment: But what about the function returned by the anonymous function?

Comment: I updated my answer with a more clear explanation and another example.

Comment: Perfect.Thanks a lot for explaining things in detail.You are absolutely right

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you, if you feel this answer helped you would you mind accepting it as the answer? Just trying to build up rep for site privileges. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your anonymous function 

`function(){
return function(){
console.log(x)`
 
is defined on the same scope (global) as `outerFunction`, but x is defined inside the scope `outerFunction`.

The scope of the function is set at the moment the function is defined, rather than at the moment when a function is assigned to variable.

Comment: Yes thats true.I understand this.But the value of 'myCallbackRet ' is the function returned from the anonymous function.As such it will become property of the Activation Object of the outer function with name 'myCallbackRet '.So,it should form closure over the outer function 'outerFunction'

Comment: I edited the answer to include explanation to your comment @Bauwa